# How do I get a jQuery function to work with specific elements when they have the same class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

I have sections (divs) with text in it, but when the text is too long I made it so the text "fades" (with css) and displays a "show more" button, which shows the full text for that specific div when clicked. The problem is that it only works for the first div, and I believe it's because they all have the same class and id name. What's the best way to get around that? Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="fade-container">
  <div id="fade-content">
   <p>
    Long text goes here...
    <div class="fade-anchor"><span class="btn-primary round-xl small btn-shadow">Show more</span></div>
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$('.fade-anchor').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fade-content').css('max-height','none');
    $('.fade-anchor').remove();
});
</script>
```

By the way, info is being fetched from the database in a php while loop.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id. Just use classes.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.fade-content').toggleClass('open')` is your friend, after having changed id to class ^^

Comment: Thanks. I'm not that experienced yet, but I now remember that about IDs. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user clicks on `.fade-anchor` you can use `this`to get the element currently selected, you should also use classes instead of ids for multiple elements, like so:

```
$('.fade-anchor').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.fade-content').css('max-height','none');
    $(this).hide(); // Maybe you should hide instead of removing, in case you want to add a toggle effect later on.
});
```

You can also check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vh8e1dg/) with the working version.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much Lucas! This works. Thanks for taking the time to help a newbie like myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can achieve it by e.currentTarget

$('.fade-anchor').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(e.currentTarget).css('max-height','none');
$('.fade-anchor').remove();});
```